# Typescript import a variable from a module and keep it updated

Tags: typescript

say i have 2 TS files (modules).

```
//foo.ts
export let count;
count = updateCount();

//bar.ts
import { count } from 'foo.ts';
console.log(count);
```

this results:
**undefined**
because, if i got it right **count** got imported before its value is updated(assigned).

so my Question is how to import it and keep it updated in Typescript.